# jQuery: Allow text selection inside <a>

Tags: jquery, html, css

When trying to select text inside a, it's just dragging link.

Is it possible to disable this behavior while keeping link clickable?

Thanks ;)

Comment: You might be able to just add a click event handler to a `<span/>` or `<div/>` tag and color it like a link / mouse pointer with CSS. It should then have no problem selecting text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a fake link with CSS on a span and bind your events.

Use `:hover` CSS selector

I made it for you with this [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexBay/Hzcz9/1/)

Comment: Guess i'll require some rest. My head is not working properly. If i can't find so simple solutions. :D

Comment: Please not that a such fake link will behave quite differently from a real one (e.g not showing target URL in the status bar, no reaction on mouse middle button click, potential accessibility problems etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I think inside an `<a>` it is not possible, because the dragging is the behaviour of a lot of browsers to allow drag and drop of links betweens applications. You could work around this using JavaScript and by using another HTML element as a link, but that is miss-use in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `cursor: text` rule.

```
a {
   cursor: text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible in your case, I would instead make it a label with onclick handler defined.

Instead of

```
<a href="google.com">MY LINK</a>
```

use

```
<label href="google.com" onclick="navigate()">MY LINK</label>

function navigate() {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
}
```

with proper style.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vcBRA/1/